# Enumerating with multiple cursors?

Tags: multiple-cursors

Say you would for instance define 5 variables with multiple cursors and you wanted to name them x_i where i ∈ {1,2,3,4,5}. Instead of writing 5 rows with x_ and then filling the rest manually, is there any way this could be done with multiple cursors?

I.e. like https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry for sublime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**, it's possible with [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el).

[image]

- Let's say you have atleast 5 consecutive empty lines.
- With the cursor at the topmost empty line, create 5 multiple cursors by keeping on hitting `C->` (default binding for `mc/mark-next-like-this`).
- Type the common variable prefix: `x_` as per your example.
- Insert numbers starting with the prefix you specify (default starting number is `0`) to `mc/insert-numbers`. For your example, you would do `C-u 1 M-x mc/insert-numbers`.
- Hit `C-g` or `RET` to exit multiple cursors mode.

---

**Alternative way using the [`tiny`](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny) package**

Type `m1\n5|x_%d` and `M-x tiny-expand`.

*The best part is that you can `undo` and get back to that expression, tweak it, `M-x tiny-expand`, repeat, ..*

---

`tiny` syntax [cheat-sheet](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-tiny.el)

```
mBSEO|F
 ││││--
 │││││└──> (optional) Format - %x | 0x%x | %c | %s | %(+ x x) | %014.2f | %03d 
 ││││└───> (optional) Pipe character used if Format specified for reading clarity
 │││└────> (optional) Lisp Operation - *xx | (* x x) | (+ x ?A) | *2+3x | (* 2 (+ 3 x))
 ││└─────> End value
 │└──────> (optional) Separator - Space | , | \n (default=Space)
 └───────> (optional) Begin value (default=0)
- No space allowed between 'm' and 'B'
- No space allowed between 'E' and 'O'
```

Answer (score 5):

This can also easily be done with built-in features of Emacs, namely
keyboard macros. Let's say, as in kashualmodi's answer, that you want
to write this:

```
x_1
x_2
x_3
x_4
x_5
```

You can type: `C-1 <f3> x_ <f3> RET C-5 <f4>`. Step by step:

- `C-1 <f3>`: the `<f3>` starts recording a keyboard macro, each
  keyboard macro gets its own counter which starts at 0 by default;
  the `C-1` makes the counter start at 1 for this macro.
- `x_`: `x_` obviously just inserts that text into the buffer.
- `<f3>`: during a macro recording `<f3>` inserts the current value of
  the counter and increments it by one.
- `RET`: add a newline.
- `C-5 <f4>`: `<f4>` stops recording if you are recording and runs the
  most recent keyboard macro if you are not recording. Here we combine
  these functions: the `C-5` means "do 5 `<f4>`s", so it will stop the
  recording and then execute the macro 4 more times ---I think of
  it as "5 executions, counting the one I just recorded".

Comment: What about a,b,c? or FE FF 100? Is there a counter for abc too?