# quickly duplicate line and increase number for lots of lines

Tags: key-bindings

I have a file like this:

```
1 = "go 1"
2 = "go 2"
3 = "go 3"
```

I want duplicate the last line and increase both numbers. The needed amount of lines is very high (approximately 90), so I want to automate a little.

The result should look like that:

```
1 = "go 1"
2 = "go 2"
3 = "go 3"
4 = "go 4"
5 = "go 5"
6 = "go 6"

[...]

88 = "go 88"
89 = "go 89"
90 = "go 90"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. The current question looks like you could just append a line `91 = "go 91"`. Maybe, you can add a small example for 5 lines with the text before and after the edit.

Comment: Okay, now I got it. The original text has only 3 lines and you want to duplicate the last line 87 times such that the final text has 90 lines.

Comment: You could do `M-: (loop for i from 4 to 90 do (insert (format "  %d = \"go %d\"\n" i i)))` behind the line ` 3 = "go 3"`.

Comment: Check out the solution using `tiny` package [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17886/115).

Comment: @Tobias When i execute your code, i get this error message: http://paste.debian.net/713271/  (i used emacs -q $file for that)

Comment: `loop` is an alias for `cl-loop` from the `cl-macs`-package. You get it if you load `cl-lib`. I always do that since I am using elisp rather often.

Comment: @Tobias do you want to move your comment into an answer so that i can upvote it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use the [`tiny`](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny) package (also available from Melpa).

```
m1\n90|%d = "go %d"
```

Simply type the above and do `M-x tiny-expand`.

The below linked reference to another emacs.SE Q&A provides details on how to use this *tiny* syntax.

---

### [image]

**Reference**: [Solution to *Enumerating with multiple cursors?*](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17886/115)

Comment: Your code expands in my setup to `(mapconcat (lambda(x) (let ((lst (list x))) (format "%d = \"go %d" (nth 0 lst) x)))(number-sequence 1 90) "\n")"` using https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny#setup

Comment: @toogley What version of emacs are you on? (this worked fine for me on 24.5 and works fine on the latest emacs-25 pretest too). Does the same thing happen if you call `tiny-expand` in an `emacs -Q` session (with just the `tiny.el` loaded)? Is that only thing that happens is that string gets pasted? You get no errors? In any case, please report back if you get backtrace after doing `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, and then `M-x tiny-expand` with the point at the end of `m1\n90|%d = "go %d"`. **Also it would be helpful to post this as an issue on the package github.**

Comment: The error was caused by the position of my cursor. After typing/inserting the above, my cusor was targeting the quote character instead of a space afterwards. Would you mind adding that condition to your post, just for clarification.  Thanks :)

Comment: @toogley Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by that. After you type `m1\n90|%d = "go %d"`, your cursor will be directly after the last double quote there. And then you do `M-x tiny-expand`. That works fine as you see in the gif.

Comment: Ah sry, I forgot to note: I'm using the evil package. After leaving the insert mode, the cursor is placed upon the last character.

Answer (score 4):

You can use keyboard macros.  Try this:

```
<f3>                    ;; (start macro)

<f3>                    ;; (insert counter)
SPC                     ;; self-insert-command
=                       ;; self-insert-command
SPC                     ;; self-insert-command
"go                     ;; self-insert-command * 3
SPC                     ;; self-insert-command
C-u C-x C-k C-a         ;; (reset counter to previous value)
<f3>                    ;; (insert counter)
"                       ;; self-insert-command
C-e                     ;; move-end-of-line
RET                     ;; newline

<f4>                    ;; (end macro)
C-u 99 <f4>             ;; (repeat macro 99 times)
```

This will create lines starting with `0 = "go 0"` all the way through `99 = "go 99"`.  If you wanted to start at a different number, you could press `C-u 42 C-x C-k C-c` before recording the macro to start the counter at 42 instead of 0.